# Converting list of polygons to multipolygon using shapely?

Tags: python, polygon, shapely

I have a list of polygons where each polygon is a `wkt` form as follows:

```
list_polygons =  ['POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))', 'POLYGON ((-88.121359263 41.887694051,-88.12027565 41.887654116,-88.120264921 41.884451192,-88.11968556399999 41.884483142,-88.11962119099999 41.882669946,-88.121251974 41.882637995,-88.121359263 41.887694051))']
```

I want to convert into a multi polygon `wkt` as   `['MULTIPOLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))', 'POLYGON ((-88.121359263 41.887694051,-88.12027565 41.887654116,-88.120264921 41.884451192,-88.11968556399999 41.884483142,-88.11962119099999 41.882669946,-88.121251974 41.882637995,-88.121359263 41.887694051))']`

I tried the following but gives me `assertion error`:

```
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon
Multipolygon(list_polygons)
```

I also tried to debug like this

```
p = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200
029))')
*** SyntaxError: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<string>', 1, 1, "= wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))')"))
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55802669/how-can-i-convert-list-of-polygons-to-multipolygon

Answer (score 4):

This works for me under shapely '1.6.4.post1':

```
import shapely.wkt
import shapely.geometry

list_wkt = ['POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))', 'POLYGON ((-88.121359263 41.887694051,-88.12027565 41.887654116,-88.120264921 41.884451192,-88.11968556399999 41.884483142,-88.11962119099999 41.882669946,-88.121251974 41.882637995,-88.121359263 41.887694051))']

list_polygons =  [shapely.wkt.loads(poly) for poly in list_wkt]

print( shapely.geometry.MultiPolygon(list_polygons) )
```

Resulting in:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((-88.131229288 41.900200029, -88.12973798 41.900104202, -88.12978599900001 41.894907769, -88.131352409 41.895051521, -88.131229288 41.900200029)), ((-88.121359263 41.887694051, -88.12027565 41.887654116, -88.120264921 41.884451192, -88.11968556399999 41.884483142, -88.11962119099999 41.882669946, -88.121251974 41.882637995, -88.121359263 41.887694051)))
```

This is difficult to say what is not working for you as you don't provide full code but your last line works in my system:

```
p = shapely.wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-88.131229288 41.900200029,-88.12973798 41.900104202,-88.129785999 41.894907769,-88.131352409 41.895051521,-88.131229288 41.900200029))')
```

Comment: @HitchamZouarhi what is new in your answer from this previously posted one? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251389/when-is-using-an-other-posters-content-plagiarism

Comment: check your previous version, IMO the core of the answer is converting a list of strings to a list of Polygons ( which was missing from your previous answer )

Answer (score 1):

You could transform each wkt polygon to a shapely polygon then create a multipolygon:

```
import shapely.geometry as geom
polygons = [wkt.loads(wkt_string) for wkt_string in list_polygons]
multi_polygon = geom.MultiPolygon(polygons)
```