# Shapely 2.0 from list of polygons to multipolygons

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, list, multi-polygon

I have a geoJson file that contains some Regions boundaries. Based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/320734/135455) I made the following code to transform the boundaries coordinates into a `MultiPolygon` Shapely object.

```
import json
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Poing, shape

bound_multply = []
bound_names = []

with open(fname, encoding="utf-8") as geoJsonFile:
    GeoData = json.load(geoJsonFileName)

for bound in GeoData['features']:
    if bound.get('properties').get('type')=='boundary':
        bound_shape = shape(bound['geometry'])
        bound_multply.append(bound_shape)
        bound_names.append(bound['properties']['name'])
bound_polygon = MultiPolygon(bound_multply)
```

The problem is that, where I execute the instruction

```
bound_polygon = MultiPolygon(bound_multply)
```

I get a deprecation warning.

> /Users/myname/Project1/env1/lib/python3.10/site-packages/shapely/geometry/multipolygon.py:202:
> ShapelyDeprecationWarning: **getitem** for multi-part geometries is
> deprecated and will be removed in Shapely 2.0. Use the `geoms`
> property to access the constituent parts of a multi-part geometry.
> shell = ob[0]

I looked over the documentation and the [migration tutorial](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migration.html#multi-part-geometries-will-no-longer-be-sequences-length-iterable-indexable) but I can't understand what's wrong with my code and where I am supposed to use the `geoms` property.

Just to be clear, these are the type:

- **bound_shape:** <class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>
- **bound_multply:** <class 'list'>
- **bound_polygon:** <class 'shapely.geometry.multipolygon.MultiPolygon'>

*I don't consider my question a duplicate of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/320734/135455) as mine is specifically about Shapely 2.0.*

The code works fine but how can I edit the snippet for working also with Shapely 2.0?

Comment: Possibly a bug. What is `bound_multply` as list of? Could you make a small example? Also, what version of Shapely are you using?

Comment: Sure, I am using Shapely 1.8.5.post1. You can find a geojson file and the script code to reproduce the error here https://gist.github.com/simboli/ff57bff0c1412a2437e07cf10d56967f . Thanks!